# Number of abelian groups Vs Number of non-abelian groups

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups

I would like to see a table that shows the number of non-abelian group for every order n. It is a preferable if the table contains the number of abelian groups of order n (this is not necessary though). If anyone could provide me with such a table , I would be grateful.

Note: I already checked wikipedia. They have a table similar to the one I want but its small.

Here is a simliar table to the one I want:

http://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_order_n#Table_of_number_of_distinct_groups_of_order_n

Thank you

Comment: How large orders do you need? GAP can produce these numbers quickly up to order around $2000$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes 2000 is probably large enough.

Comment: The OEIS links in the WP article contain ready-made lists of these numbers up to at least 2000.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I seem unable to find where the link is.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I found it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's a reference-request and the amounts given there seem sufficient:

The number of goups of order $n$ is listed at OEIS as [A00001](http://oeis.org/A000001). On its description page is a link to a [table of $n$, $a_n$ for $n=1,\ldots, 2047$](http://oeis.org/A000001/b000001.txt). For abelian groups, [A000688](http://oeis.org/A000688) lsts the counts [up to $n=10000$](http://oeis.org/A000688/b000688.txt) as these are quite easily calculated.

Intriguingly, [A060689](http://oeis.org/A060689) (non-abelian groups) gives only a list up to [$n=2015$](http://oeis.org/A060689/b060689.txt), sou you can earn merit by computing the differences from the tables and submit a bigger table.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the GAP functions which will allow you to get these numbers:

NumberSmallGroups(n) : gives you the number of groups of order $n$

IdsOfAllSmallGroups : Gives you a list consisting of the ID of each of the groups satisfying the criteria given (type ?IdsOfAllSmallGroups to get a description of the syntax). Note that this will not work for certain orders, as there are just too many such groups. In those cases, you can compute the number of abelian groups by hand, since these just involve the number of partitions of some not too large numbers.

To get the number of the groups, use the function Size() which returns the number of elements in a list.

The above function can also be used to get groups with suitable other properties, such as solvable, nilpotent, M-groups and any other property you might want.

Comment: Another useful function is `SmallGroupsInformation`, which, among other details, tells also which properties/attributes are precomputed and stored. For these, selection will be much faster. I guess, `IsAbelian` is precomputed in most cases.